# SQL SELECT query - ignore empty/NULL field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `fruit`
WHERE ingredient1 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient2 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient3 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient4 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient5 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
```

The variables are either simply the name itself ($Aardbei being 'Aardbei', $Appel being 'Appel', etc.) or empty (as in '', not actually unset or NULL)
The table in question can have the 'ingredient' fields as empty, and if the variable is also empty, it matches that, which is not what I want.

How can I make it so that an empty variable in the query is ignored, instead of matched to an empty field in the SQL table?

Comment: check before building your query if *empty()* your vars and then build your query with filled onces

Comment: BTW you should change your table design. It is not normalized. Add a `fruit_ingredient` and an `ingredients` table

Comment: @Donald - Pretty sure that will result in multiple errors, because I'm trying to use variables that aren't set, but I'll try.

Comment: @Juergen - Having multiple different ingredients in one single field sounds like the optimal situation, but I have no idea how to do that. I'm gonna follow the rule of KISS.

Comment: Having multilpe values in a single column is the worst thing you can do! Never do that.

Comment: Thought that was what you meant... Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to fix the table so it contains `NULL` values rather than empty string values.  You can do this in one shot as:

```
update fruit
    set ingredient1 = nullif(ingredient1, ''),
        ingredient2 = nullif(ingredient2, ''),
        . . .;
```

Because `NULL` does not match anything, it will not match `''`.

I should point out that you can do the same thin in the `where`:

```
where nullif(ingredient1, '') in . . . or
      nullif(ingredient2, '') in . . .
```

The better answer, though, is that having multiple columns represent an "array" of values is not a good design in SQL.  Instead, you want a `FruitIngredients` table, with one row per `Fruit` and `Ingredient`.  This would also simplify your query.

Comment: 1. I have tried doing so, can send you screencaps of my table settings if you'd like.

Comment: 2. That's honestly just confusing me further. No idea what you mean. I'd prefer to just work with what I have.

Comment: Nullified all the empty fields, works perfectly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use as per below-

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `fruit`
WHERE ingredient1 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient2 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient3 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient4 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
OR ingredient5 IN ('$Aardbei','$Appel','$Banaan','$Mango','$Perzik','$Sinaasappel','$Peer','$Pruim','$Kiwi')
AND ingredient1<>'' AND ingredient2<>'' AND ingredient3<>'' AND ingredient4<>'' AND ingredient5<>'';
```

Comment: It's returning less of the unwanted columns, but still some. For instance, when I only look for 'Appel', it returns a column with only the first two fields filled, with neither actually being 'Appel'.

Comment: @Makkebakke: Not getting your point as here whatever variables you pass in these 5 fields but at the end query will exclude if any column contains '' (blank) value...is not...